Resizing a MenuBarExtra Window
I’m working on a MenuBarExtra with a .window style. I know that I can set the frame size, either with a hard-coded value or through a stored variable.
Is it possible to make the window resizable by dragging on the edges?

I don't think this is supported in SwiftUI so you'd have to use some AppKit APIs.
Create an NSViewRepresentable, and access the window.styleMask property in your custom NSView. Simply insert the .resizable flag in there,
struct Helper: NSViewRepresentable {
    
    class HelperView: NSView {
        override func viewWillMove(toWindow newWindow: NSWindow?) {
            super.viewWillMove(toWindow: newWindow)
            Task {
                newWindow?.styleMask.insert(.resizable)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> HelperView {
        HelperView()
    }
    
    func updateNSView(_ nsView: HelperView, context: Context) {
    }
}

MenuBarExtra("Foo") {
    ZStack {
        Helper(width: $width, height: $height)
        Text("Bar")
            .padding()
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
}
.menuBarExtraStyle(.window)

However, this doesn't retain the new size after you close the window. If you want to do that, it is a bit more complicated. You need to create a way for the custom NSView to tell SwiftUI what size it has been resized to.
Here I am consuming the didEndLiveResizeNotification, and updating two bindings,
struct Helper: NSViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var width: Double
    @Binding var height: Double
    
    class HelperView: NSView {
        var cancellable: AnyCancellable?
        var didChangeSize: ((CGSize) -> Void)?
        override func viewWillMove(toWindow newWindow: NSWindow?) {
            super.viewWillMove(toWindow: newWindow)
            Task {
                newWindow?.styleMask.insert(.resizable)
            }
            cancellable = NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: NSWindow.didEndLiveResizeNotification, object: newWindow)
                .sink { [weak self] _ in
                    self?.didChangeSize?(newWindow?.contentView?.bounds.size ?? .zero)
                }
        }
    }
    
    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> HelperView {
        HelperView()
    }
    
    func updateNSView(_ nsView: HelperView, context: Context) {
        nsView.didChangeSize = {
            width = $0.width
            height = $0.height
        }
    }
}

Then you can use it like this:
@State private var height: Double = 100
@State private var width: Double = 100

// ...

MenuBarExtra("Foo") {
    ZStack {
        Helper(width: $width, height: $height)
        Text("Bar")
            .padding()
            .frame(maxWidth: width, maxHeight: height)
    }
}
.menuBarExtraStyle(.window)

